# Building URLs with concatinate

Tags: python, url, concatenation

Trying to build a URL using the variables I've already setup and then a known part of the URL on the back end. The code will throw the following error:

**TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects**

```
block_explorer_url  = "https://blockexplorer.com/api/addrs/"
#?from=0&to=50

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Collect and visualize Bitcoin transactions and any related hidden services.')

parser.add_argument("--graph",help="Output filename of the graph file. Example: bitcoin.gexf",default="bitcoingraph.gexf")
parser.add_argument("--address", help="A bitcoin address to begin the search on.",)


args = parser.parse_args()

bitcoin_address = args.address
graph_file      = args.graph

# 
# Retrieve all bitcoin transactions for a Bitcoin address
#
def get_all_transactions(bitcoin_address):

    transactions = []
    from_number  = 0
    to_number    = 50

    block_explorer_url_full = block_explorer_url + bitcoin_address + "/txs?from=%d&to=%d" % (from_number,to_number)
```

Logically, having the variables there and then adding on the rest of the URL as a string makes since to me. Where am I going astray?

Comment: Specifically it's this line that it's angry at:

**block_explorer_url_full = block_explorer_url + bitcoin_address + "/txs?from=%d&to=%d" % (from_number,to_number)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when `bitcoin_address` is `None` (not provided by user), your program still tries to concatenate it to a `str`, which definitely won't work.

To solve that, you could add some code that checks the result of `parse_args` and raises an error when that happens, such as this:

```
if args.address is None:
    raise ValueError('A bitcoin address must be provided.')
```

Separately, while your approach to string formatting is *generally* correct, you should consider moving away from C-style formatting and towards the `format` method, for example:

At the start of your script:

```
base_url = 'https://blockexplorer.com/api/addrs/{address}/txs?from={from}&to={to}'
```

And later in the function:

```
full_url = base_url.format(address=bitcoin_address,
                           from=from_number,
                           to=to_number)
```